# 110cc scooter sputters under acceleration. Resetting ECU a temporary fix

Tags: honda, electronic-control-module, scooter

This is driving my crazy. The dealership is just throwing parts at it. First time, they hooked it up to a little cylinder which has a guage and is connected to pressurized air and connects to the fuel assembly unit. 3 mins later, they ruled the fuel pump is bad, so they replaced it.

Everthing ran fine after that... for a day. The next day I'm back at the dealer with the same problem. This time they reset the ECU. It ran fine, for a few hours.

3rd day they open it back up and recheck everything for an hour. Conclusion? They said it is working fine now. I asked them what they did and they said they reset the ECU. But didn't you do that yesterday? Isn't t it obvious that that's just a temporary fix. So now I'm helping them figure out what's wrong. I suggested the TPS. They took that... 30 mins later, they want me to try out the bike. I'm telling them it's useless because now that you reset the ECU, I know the bike is going to run fine, but the problem will return in a few hours. So they say they also changed the TPS and that that was most likely the culprit.

But... just like I predicted, 5 hours later, same problem.

Any idea what it could be? It sputters under acceleration. Feels like it's running out of gas. It's 2016 Honda Scoopy with stop idle option. And yeah...spark plug was changed.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!